# Convert column containing string and NAN to list of integers in Pandas

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that I read from a CSV file, which contains some columns that contain lists.  However they end up as a strings in Pandas, like column B in this example.  I would like to turn this column into a new column containing a list of integers.  A couple of complications.  1) The original column has some NaN values in it. This has prevented ast.literal_eval from working for me.  2) If possible, I'd like all of the resulting lists to be the same length (the length of the longest list in that column), padded out with NAN. So in the end it should look like Column C, in which each element is a list of ints.  This is as close as I have got.  So I have got a list of strings, but not integers, and not padded out to the maximum length.  Well, at least that's how I think it is! :-)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : (1,2,3), 'B': ('[0,1]',np.nan,'[0,1,2]'), \
     'C': ([0,1,np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[0,1,2])})
df['D'] = df['B'].str.replace(']','').str.replace('[','').str.split('\W')
display("Starting point: ", df['B'][0])
display("What I want: ", df['C'][0])
display("What I have so far:  ", df['D'][0])
```

This is the output from the above:

```
Starting point: 
[0,1]
What I want: 
[0, 1, nan]
What I have so far:  
['0', '1']
```

Any help would be very much appreciated and would save me lots of hair.

Comment: I think you have to iterate all lists in column D to get the maximum length. Then you can extend all shorter lists like this: 

```aList.extend(np.nan*(maxLen - len(aList)))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get it done:

```
b = df.B.str.extract(r'\[(.*)\]', expand=False).str.split(',', expand=True).fillna(np.nan)
df['D'] = pd.DataFrame(b.apply(lambda x: tuple(x.values))).applymap(list)
```

Comment: Thanks piRSquared!  One small addition was to put ,axis=1 after the (x.values), otherwise it does the list along the column instead of the row.  So it becomes:  df['D'] = pd.DataFrame(b.apply(lambda x: tuple(x.values),axis=1)).applymap(list)